# docker forgets to install dependency from requirements file

Tags: python, django, docker, pip, celery

I am trying to troubleshoot [a tutorial on udemy](https://www.udemy.com/course/detailed-django-rest-api/learn/lecture/31039570#questions/18547228) on Windows 10 but when I run my containers the django app does not seem to want to load celery as a module.  I tried a few different versions but still get the same error message.  The celery worker seems fine.  Does anyone here see my issue and help me understand what is happening?

The tutorial's  [original code is here on his github](https://github.com/API-Imperfect/authors-haven-api-live) but most of my code is a straight copy from him.  Here is a [link to the repo](https://github.com/justin107d/author-haven-api) of what I have covered so far.

**error message:**

```
postgres             | 2022-11-14 03:17:27.850 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
flower               | PostgreSQL is ready!!!!.....:-)
celery_worker        | PostgreSQL is ready!!!!.....:-)
django-api           | PostgreSQL is ready!!!!.....:-)
django-api           | Traceback (most recent call last):
django-api           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
django-api           |     self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
django-api           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
django-api           |     output = self.handle(*args, **options)
django-api           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 86, in wrapped
django-api           |     saved_locale = translation.get_language()
django-api           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 254, in get_language
django-api           |     return _trans.get_language()
django-api           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 57, in __getattr__
django-api           |     if settings.USE_I18N:
django-api           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 82, in __getattr__
django-api           |     self._setup(name)
django-api           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 69, in _setup
django-api           |     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
django-api           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 170, in __init__
django-api           |     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
django-api           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
django-api           |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
django-api           |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
django-api           |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
django-api           |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked
django-api           |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
django-api           |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
django-api           |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
django-api           |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked
django-api           |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
django-api           |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
django-api           |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
django-api           |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
django-api           |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
django-api           |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
django-api           |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
django-api           |   File "/app/authors_api/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
django-api           |     from .celery import app as celery_app
django-api           |   File "/app/authors_api/celery.py", line 3, in <module>
django-api           |     from celery import Celery
django-api           | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'celery'
```

the file the error is referring to is:

**celery.py**

```py
import os

from celery import Celery  # <--- Issue is with this line ---
from django.conf import settings

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "authors_api.settings.local")

app = Celery("authors_api")

app.config_from_object("django.conf:settings", namespace="CELERY")

app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

**base.txt**

```py
django==3.2.11
django-environ==0.8.1
djangorestframework==3.12.4
django-cors-headers==3.10.1
django-filter==21.1
django-autoslug==1.9.8
django-countries==7.2.1
django-phonenumber-field==5.2.0
phonenumbers==8.12.33
drf-yasg==1.20.0 

Pillow==9.0.0

argon2-cffi==21.3.0

pytz==2021.3 

redis==4.1.0
# celery==5.2.3 # original from tutorial
# celery==5.2.7 # current
celery==5.1 # does not work either
flower==1.0.0
django-celery-email==3.0.0

djoser==2.1.0
djangorestframework-simplejwt==4.8.0
PyJWT==2.1.0

django-haystack==3.1.1 
drf-haystack==1.8.11

# this is supposed to be good for small projects but Solr and Xapian are supposed to be better alternatives
Whoosh==2.7.4
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by completely deleting the image and rebuilding it from scratch.